# VueJS dynamic routes and components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Using cue-cli 3. Is it possible to do this (router.js):

```
axios.get( `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_DOMAIN}/wp-json/api/v1/routes`).then( r => r.data ).then(routes => {
    routes.pages.forEach( (e) => {
        router.addRoutes([
            {
                path: `/${e.slug}`,
                component: e.template,
            },
        ]);
    });
});
```

e.template is a string 'Default' and of course VueJS says:
`route config "component" for path: /privacy-policy cannot be a string id. Use an actual component instead.` Tried with `Vue.component(e.template)` no luck.

What I want to do here is create dynamic routes based on XHR response.

Here is all router.js code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import Default from './views/Default.vue'
import Test from './views/Test.vue'
import axios from "axios";

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
  ]
});

axios.get( `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_DOMAIN}/wp-json/api/v1/routes`).then( r => r.data ).then(routes => {
    routes.pages.forEach( (e) => {
        router.addRoutes([
            {
                path: `/${e.slug}`,
                component: e.template,
            },
        ]);
    });
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I ended up with this solution:

```
function getComponent(name) {

    let component = null;

    switch(name)
    {
        case 'Default':
            component = Default;
            break;

        case 'Test':
            component = Test;
            break;
    }

    return component;

}

axios.get( `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_DOMAIN}/wp-json/api/v1/routes`).then( r => r.data ).then(routes => {
    routes.pages.forEach( (e) => {
        router.addRoutes([
            {
                path: `/${e.slug}`,
                component: getComponent(e.template),
            },
        ]);
    });
});
```

Another one more cleaner solution:

```
const components = { Default, Test }

axios.get( `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_DOMAIN}/wp-json/api/v1/routes`).then( r => r.data ).then(routes => {
    routes.pages.forEach( (e) => {
        router.addRoutes([
            {
                path: `/${e.slug}`,
                component: components[e.template],
            },
        ]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If `e.template` stores the template string,

You should wrap it as one options object like `{template: e.template, props: {}, data: function () {} }`, then call `Vue.extend` to construct the component.

or you can ignore `Vue.extend` because Vue will call `Vue.extend` to construct the component automatically.

Check the usage at [Vue Guide: Vue.component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component)

**Edit** as the OP states `e.tempate` is one component name:

if `e.template` is the name of component, uses `Vue.component(e.template)`.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
  ]
})

Vue.component('test', {
  template: '<div>I am Predefined component -> {{index}}</div>',
  props: ['index']
})

let routerIndex = 1
setInterval(()=> {
  let newComponent = routerIndex%2 ? {template: '<div>I am User -> {{index}}</div>', props: ['index']} : Vue.component('test')
  
  router.addRoutes([{
    path: '/Test' + routerIndex,
    name: 'Test' + routerIndex,
    component: newComponent,
    props: { index: routerIndex }
  }])
  console.log('add route = ', '/Test' + routerIndex, ' by ', routerIndex%2 ? 'options object' : 'Vue.component')
  routerIndex++
}, 2000)

Vue.use(VueRouter)
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  data: {
    routeIndex: 0
  },
  watch: {
    routeIndex: function (newVal) {
      this.$router.push({'name': 'Test'+newVal})
    }
  }
})
```

```css
div.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <p>Current Route Index: {{routeIndex}}</p>
    Test Route: <input v-model="routeIndex" type="number">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes e.template is a string coming from backend, and I have tried: component: {template: e.template, props: {}, data: function () {} }, no avail.

Comment: Yes it's valid, but it;s string.

id: 2
slug: "sample-page"
template: "Test"
title: "Sample Page"
type: "page"

Comment: I mean e.template is a string of component name, not a Template HTML. For example e.template is 'Test' and component is imported like this: import Test from './views/Test.vue'

Comment: if so , change it `Vue.component(e.template)`

Comment: Tried that long time before posted this question :)  It doesn't renders anything.

Comment: Have you register that comonent first? I updated the anwser, you will see if e.template is one component name, it will work also if that component already registered.

Comment: It's importend and in Vue router when you set component: SomeComponent it will work. I have tried hardcode 1 route like this and this worked, but it doesn't work inside promise.

Comment: After change to `Vue.component(e.template)`, What is the error?

Comment: You may need to provide more codes for trouble shooting. if you can put your codes into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/), it will better.

Comment: @Sphinx Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836601/how-can-make-dynamyc-routes-on-the-vue-router